# Rank several columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, rank

I have a dataframe of monthly stock returns (each row is a month):

```
df:
            Stock A Stock B Stock C ....
Jun 1927     1%    2%        3%
Jul 1927     3%    1%        2%
Aug 1927     2%    3%        1%
Sep 1927     5%    2%        9%
...
...
```

and I I would like to rank stocks for each month based on returns and create a new dataframe based on this.

So something like this:

```
df_rank:
            Stock A Stock B Stock C
Jun 1927     1      2         3
Jul 1927     3      1         2
Aug 1927     2      3         1
Sep 1927     2      3         1
```

I was thinking of something like this:

```
df_rank<-data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = ncol(df)))
for (i in seq(1:nrow(df))){
   df1<-data.frame(rank(df[i,]))
   df_rank<-cbind(df_rank,df1)
}
```

Comment: Your question as it stands is very confusing (at least  I think it confused @akrun who is a difficult person to confuse.). It would be more clear if your number of rows were not equal to the number of stocks and the result could not be interpreted as both by stock and by month.

Comment: The number of rows is just indicative as this is a min example, the actual dataset is much larger. I am not sure why the number of rows and number of stocks being equal is confusing but I have added  a row, I am not sure if that helps.

Comment: I think it does help, although better would have been to put in actual R-code that constructed the example.

Comment: I have not downvoted your solution, I highly appreciate any help. Removing the percentages was not the solution however.

Comment: I did not realize that we are having a competition here for who gives the right answer. The solution suggested below works, but I discovered a new problem and will ask this a new post. Thanks everyone for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we have your data as a data.frame with some changes in the percentages.

```
     month StockA StockB StockC
1 Jun 1927     1%     2%     3%
2 Jul 1927     3%     1%    -4%
3 Aug 1927   6.4%     3%     4%
```

we can use apply to run a function on the rows. To get it back in the correct shape we need to apply a transpose.

```
t(apply(df[, -1], 1, rank))
     StockA StockB StockC
[1,]      1      2      3
[2,]      3      2      1
[3,]      3      1      2

# to replace the data in the data.frame
df[, -1] <- t(apply(df[, -1], 1, rank))
df
     month StockA StockB StockC
1 Jun 1927      1      2      3
2 Jul 1927      3      2      1
3 Aug 1927      3      1      2
```

Now I just ranked over the percentages as character values. You can also use akrun's function and first remove the % sign, set it to numeric and then rank.

```
t(apply(df[, -1], 1,  function(x) rank(as.numeric(sub("[%]", "", x)))))
```

In this example the outcome is the same. But with many percentages, it might be better to work with reals instead of chars.

data:

```
df <- structure(list(month = c("Jun 1927", "Jul 1927", "Aug 1927"), 
                     StockA = c("1%", "3%", "6.4%"), 
                     StockB = c("2%", "1%", "3%"), 
                     StockC = c("3%", "-4%", "4%")), 
                .Names = c("month", "StockA","StockB", "StockC"),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works well. But it appears I have a different problem with the rank command, applied to one row:  rank(df[1,])

Comment: is not producing a correct ranking in the sense that the largest returns are ranked 1 or 30 (num of stocks is 30)

Answer (score -1):

We could remove the `%` and then use `rank`:

```
df[] <- t(sapply(as.data.frame(t(df)), 
        function(x) rank(as.numeric(sub("[%]", "", x)))))
```

Comment: Thank you, but that was just a toy example. The actual percentages won't be reflective of the position. So I might have -4%, or +6.54%

Comment: I think that gives a ranking of months within stacks and what was asked for (in natural language) was a ranking across stocks within months. I realize that either the example was misleading or the natural language used was incorrect.

Comment: I think you are right. The ranking I obtain when I rank a single row like this is actually not correct: rank(df[1,])